# Is Egyptian vulture (pharaoh's chicken) meat halal?

Tags: halal-haram, meat

I was wondering if it's permissible to eat Egyptian vulture (pharaoh's chicken) meat!

Egyptian vulture, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_vulture), writes:

> The Egyptian vulture... also called the white scavenger vulture or pharaoh's chicken, is a small Old World vulture and the only member of the genus Neophron. ...
>
> On the ground, they walk with a waddling gait. They feed on a range of food, including mammal faeces (including those of humans), insects in dung, carrion, vegetable matter, and sometimes small animals.

That's what makes me question whether it's meat halal or not, since they kill with their claws!

Comment: It is not halal because birds of prey are haram and vultures are birds of prey.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE.  Here, we can (and should) [edit] posts to include pertinent information.  In this case, I've edited the question to include the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Egyptian vultures are birds of prey. Birds of prey are clearly haram as the Prophet forbade it.

> Ibn 'Abbas reported that Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) prohibited the eating of all fanged beasts of prey, and all the birds having talons. (Sahih Muslim-no.1934).

This means that birds that hunt with talons (claws) are haram to eat.

Comment: Do you have any reference regarding this specific vulture?

Comment: 'Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen (may Allaah have mercy on him) said: What is meant by talons here is not the thing [spur] that protrudes from the leg of the rooster; that is a talon but it does not catch prey with it. 

That which eats carrion, such as vultures.

The Hanafis, Shaafa’is and Hanbalis are agreed that it is haraam to eat large black crows and speckled crows, which are both types that usually eat only carrion, so they are abhorrent to those of a sound nature. This type also include vultures, because they only eat carrion, even though they do not have talons with which they catch prey.'

Comment: I got this from https://islamqa.info/en/111827 and vultures refer to all types.

Comment: There is no specific mention of this type of vulture but the same rule applies.

Answer (score 1):

The questioner, most probably, is confusing the bird of prey with the hunted bird. Bird of prey is simply used for hunting, not for eating as these are declared forbidden.